# Docusign API Delivery status only after all recipients viewed

Tags: docusignapi

Friends,

I am using Docusign API and it is working fine. Currently if I send an envelope to more than one customer, Docusign will give status as delivered only after all the recipients viewed the document.

I would like to get status as delivered even if the first recipients opened the document.

Is it possible with the Docusign API?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question and add in which DocuSign API call you are actually making that is returning the delivery status.  Chances are you are not calling the right one...

Comment: Ergin.. This is the URL https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/<myaccountId>/envelopes/<myenvelopeID>

Comment: Ok thanks that's what I suspected.  You're making the wrong call, I'll post an answer shortly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In DocuSign **Envelopes** can have status as well as **Recipients**.  For instance, let's say you have an envelope with 2 sequential recipients, the first recipient has signed, and the envelope has been sent to the second recipient.  In this scenario, the overall envelope status would be `Processing`, the first recipient status would be `Completed`, and the second recipient status would be `Delivered` (if they have viewed the envelope or `Sent` if they have not viewed it yet.

[See "Recipient Statuses" section on this page from Dev Center](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/recipients)

So instead of getting the Envelope status you need to make the API call to get Recipient status.  Details of that call are:

```
GET /accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients

Optional query strings: include_tabs={true or false}, include_extended={true or false}
```

Sample Response:

```
{
  "agents":[]
  "carbonCopies":[],
  "certifiedDeliveries":[],
  "currentRoutingOrder":"String content",
  "editors":[],
  "inPersonSigners":[],
  "intermediaries":[],
  "recipientCount":"String content",
  "signers":[{
    "deliveredDateTime": "String content",
    "recipientAuthenticationStatus":{
      "(authentication status result)":
        "eventTimestamp":"String content"
        "status":"String content"
      }
    },
    "recipientId": "String content",
    "requireIdLookup": "String content",
    "roleName":"String content",
    "routingOrder": "String content",
    "signedDateTime": "String content",
    "status": "String content",
    "email": "String content",
    "name": "String content"  }]
  }]
}
```

See [page 191](https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/rest-api-guide-v2.pdf#page=191) of DocuSign API Guide for more info